# How to pass an object to material-menu action?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components

I need to pass an object to material-menu action.

In may case, I am using a `material-list` with `material-list-item`. Each item has a menu `material-menu`.

When I select an option of the menu, I would like to pass the respective item to be used in method on `action:`

Following the list example:

[image]

Here the template (partially):

```
<material-list>
    <div *ngFor="let item of iniciativas">
        <material-list-item  class="shadow-box-list-item" elevation="2">
            <div>
                <h4>{{item.nome}}</h4>
                <material-progress class="width-300" [activeProgress]="25"></material-progress><span> 25%</span>
                <p>{{item.descricao}}</p>
           </div>
            <span class="material-list-item-secondary">
                <material-menu [menu]="menuModel">
                </material-menu>
            </span>
        </material-list-item>
    </div>
</material-list>
```

Here the Dart code (partially):

```
final MenuModel<MenuItem> menuModel = new MenuModel([new MenuItemGroup([new MenuItem('Editar', action: () => navegarParaItensTrabalho(null)), new MenuItem('Excluir', action: () => excluirItensTrabalho(null))])], icon: new Icon('menu'));
```

I was hoping to have some way to pass the DOM parameter to the function associated with the `action:` on `MenuItem`, I didn't find it.

Comment: To clarify are you trying to pass in the current item from the ng-for or the item being clicked?

Comment: The current item (in which the menu is) from the ng-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to pass in the context (item) when you are building the menuModel, and have the menuModel have the context instead of sharing the same instance.

There are two ways you can do this:

- Have a method that creates the menuModel given the item context.
  Would suggest returning a cache instance if you have already seen
  that item.
- Create a map of menuModels with item as the key. Update
  this map whenever the items change.

For the actual menu model you should be able to do:

```
createMenuModel(item) {
  return new MenuModel([new MenuItemGroup([
      new MenuItem('Editar', action: () => navegarParaItensTrabalho(item)), 
      new MenuItem('Excluir', action: () => excluirItensTrabalho(item))])],
      icon: new Icon('menu'));
}
```